# Get the congress details of each user registration in a congress is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show  in the page below the congress tile, date and also the registration date.

For that I have a `UserController` that has the index() method that should get the registrations in congresses of the user and then from each registration get the congress details of that congress so that is possible to show in the view the congress title, date and registration date of each congress registration.

I have the code below for that but is not working. Do you know where is the issue?

```
public function index() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $registrations = $user->with('registrations.congress');

    return view('users.index', compact('user', 'registrations'));
}
```

// page where i want to show the congress title, date and registration date

```
<div class="tab-content  bg-white" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active clearfix" id="generalInfo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <form method="post" action="{{route('user.updateGeneralInfo')}}" class="clearfix">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            ...
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane clearfix fade" id="myTickets" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
        ...
        @foreach($registration as $reg)
        <ul>
          <li>here is to show congress title</li>
          <li>here is to show congress date</li>
          <li>here is to show registration date</li>
          ...
        </ul>
        @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
```

Relevant Models to the question:

// Congress model

```
class Congress extends Model
{
    // A conference has many registration types
    public function ticketTypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\TicketType', 'congress_id');
    }

    public function registrations(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Registration', 'congress_id');
    }
}

// RegistrationModel
class Registration extends Model
{
    // a registration has one user that do the registration (main_participant_id)
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }

}

// TicketTypeModel
class TicketType extends Model
{

    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}
```

Tables structure:

```
registrations table: id, status, congress_id, created_at
congresses table: id, name, created_at,...
ticket type table:id, name, congres_id, created_at, ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the issue:

```
$registrations = $user->with('registrations.congress');
```

^ This returns a query builder, not the results of the relationship.

What you probably want is:

```
$registrations = $user->registrations()->with('congress')->get();
```

This assumes the `User` model has a relationship called `registrations`.

Also, you're passing in `$registrations`, but looping over `$registration`, as @Muabazalm noticed.

Next time, it will be helpful that you also include the error that you're getting.

Comment: Thanks like that it appears  with "@foreach($registrations as $reg)
                                {{$reg}}
                            @endforeach" this: "{"id":1,"status":"C","congress_id":1,"main_user_id":1,"congress":{"id":1,"name":"test","description":"","start_date":"2018-03-08 06:30:00","end_date":"2018-03-08 15:30:00"} ". Do you know how to show the name of the congress "test"? {{$reg->name}} is not working.

Comment: `{{ $reg->congress->name }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try `foreach` the `$registrations` instead of `$registration`, because of what you passed to `View`